# how to call an activity from a self created slide menu (one which found in default in navigation drawer activity) under Tabbed activity

Tags: android

I created a slide menu (one which found in default in navigation drawer activity) under a tabbed activity. I can call a fragment from the slide menu choices like shown in the code below. My question is , how can I call an activity instead of a fragment. Can anyone help me on this?  Here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

{
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager FM;
    FragmentTransaction FT;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.shitstuff);

        FM = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FT = FM.beginTransaction();
        FT.replace(R.id.containerView, new TabFragment()).commit();

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
                int id = item.getItemId();

                if (id == R.id.nav_history) {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = FM.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new HistoryFragment()).commit();

                }
                else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = FM.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new GalaryFragment()).commit();

                }

                DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
            }
        });
        android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar =(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.app_name,R.string.app_name);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
    }


}
```

Comment: By using the startActivity method obviously, although you should remember that any activity you start will replace the current foreground and to maintain the same UI, you may have to create an activity with a UI similar to this if you want it to look the way it does when you are using fragments.

Comment: i am new for android development.....so could you give me more details with example......tnx

Comment: The example is rather bulky to write, since I will essentially have to recreate everything in your activity. If it is the functions of an activity you need for this, then it is an overkill since most of Activity methods are public and can be accessed after casting the getActivity() call into an appropriate class.

Answer (score 0):

Simply call activity instead of a fragment.
If you are new to the Android, on below code "this" refers to a current activity, HistoryAcitvity is a new activity which is going to start. Before you write this code, create activity, and add that activity to manifest(if you do it in the android studio it does automatically).

`if (id == R.id.nav_history) {
              Intent historyActivity = new Intent(this ,HistoryAcitivity.class);
                startActivity(historyActivity);

                }`

Comment: I tried that but it will underline 'this, historyActivity.class' .......saying can't resolve constructor

Comment: Use "CurrentActivity.this" instead of just "this".